# Task Scheduler is not executing exe in windows server 2008 R2

Tags: scheduled-tasks, exe, windows-server-2008-r2

I have configured a Task scheduler which is supposed to run exe, but its not working.


 Exe is working fine as a stand alone & also in these cases :

- When we enable option "Run only when the user is logged on".
- Under "Change User or group" when we select Administrators.

**Task Scheduler is not working when I try to run it as a Local Account i.e, the account with which I am logging in.**


I have tried most of the option present in blogs like setting Start In paramaeter,executing via cmd.exe.

I tried to add Local Account to the Administrators group also but still no luck.

Comment: Could you wrap it into a batch file and capture the output from the wrapper?

Answer (score 1):

Have you selected the "*Run whether user is logged-in or not*" check box? You will then be asked to supply the account credentials. Note that the job won't run if it requires network resources and you've selected the check box "*Do not store password*". More details [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722152.aspx).

I normally use the [LocalService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684188(v=vs.85).aspx) or [NetworkService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684272(v=vs.85).aspx) account.

You might also want to look at the Windows event log to see if either the executable or the Task Scheduler itself produced an exception. Additionally the Scheduled Task viewer has a "*Last Result*" column with a result value.